# Using parameterized cascading prompts in SSRS using ODBC for RedShift

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, amazon-redshift, prompt, cascading

I am using SSRS 2014 and Visual Studio to develop a report that has cascading prompts with multi value parameters.  I am connecting to AWS RedShift with an ODBC connection.  This driver does not allow the native multi value parameter to be passed.  My report has 4 parameters that users select to get the desired report.  I have figured out how to get the final dataset (query) to provide the expected results with multi values.  I am having trouble with the cascading prompts.  I solved the final query for the body of my report by using:  (Expression:  text to form the query string)

```
="SELECT * FROM internal_reporting.Progress_Report_Rows as r WHERE (r.progress_report_run_id = ?) AND (r.IID IN ('" & Join(Parameters!pschool.Value,"','") & "'))"
```

For the parameters, I tried the same technique for the datasets that I use for each parameter but with the expression in there, I could not select the value or the name in the available or default value tabs on the parameter properties.  I then tried to use:

```
=Join(Parameters!peclist.Value,"'")
```

In the parameter tab of the data set that that fed the prompt.  My query works when I select a single @peclist value.  I get the desired results in the next cascading prompt.  If I pick more than one, the next cascading prompt is blank with no results.

What am I missing?  Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks